# AsyncTask vs Task

Tags: android, android-intent, concurrency, android-asynctask

As far as I know, in Android you can do some concurrent code using `AsyncTask` (if it's a quick code to run) and `IntentService` (if it's a long running code), but learning more about the `Google Maps API` I found the `Task` class as well, under the package `com.google.android.gms.tasks`.

- **When is `Task` better than `AsyncTask`?**
- **Why did Google Maps even bothered to create a new concurrent runner class?**

Comment: there are a lot of abstractions and a lot of classes: RxJava, Kotlin's Courutines, JobScheduler's job, SyncAdapter, etc.

Comment: Well, but all of them are from different companies right? I supposed Google should have their one and stick to it, or explain why to use another

Comment: JobScheduler, SyncAdapter, LoaderManager - are from google, there are also Future, Handler, Thread and others... the point is that in Google there is no single strategy and all teams could work on similar projects and create different bicycles... as an example there were Agera (google's Rx) and other dead-born projects. Normally you should use AsyncTask - it's part of official API, on other hand .gms.Task is part of 3rd party library and it could be dropped at any point

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with the Google Maps `Task` class, but I've (just now) read through the documentation for it as well as some subclasses.

It seems as though the `Task` class was created to represent a much more generic idea of "work" than the `AsyncTask` class. The Google Maps `Task` class and its subclasses handle canceling and resuming tasks, the ability to "check" to see if the task is completed, and a whole lot more.

`AsyncTask`, on the other hand, has a very narrow purpose in life: to easily allow you to move a long-running task **off of the UI thread** while still being able to update your UI in response to "progress" events or when the task is finished.

> When is Task better than AsyncTask?

To the average programmer: almost never. Any time you want to e.g. download an image from a URL and then display it in an `ImageView`, you should just use `AsyncTask` (or one of the many image libraries available).

> Why did Google Maps even bothered to create a new concurrent runner class?

To solve a different class of problems than `AsyncTask` is built to handle.

Comment: I would say they're just completely different.

Comment: Well, but the way you described them, `Task` appears to be an extension of `AsyncTask`, providing more methods to control/check the asynchronous computing.

Comment: Well Tasks by themselves are not asynchronous. It's more about how to encapsulate a package of "work" and how to present / return its result. And the real power of tasks come in handy, if you need to chain those packages of work or if you need sequentiall processing of multiple tasks after each other, using the result from the previous tasks.

Comment: Furthermore, now since Firebase is using Tasks, it becomes even more convenient to use tasks all together.